# Nested Datagrid ItemsSource Binding

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, nested

Here is the technical dilemma:

•   I have to create a hierarchical grid in Silverlight 5 that can go as many as four levels deep. This will require nesting grids within grids, so that any row can be selected and the appropriate child records are brought back

•   I need to do lazy loading as selections are made to access child records

•   I am using a WCF Service to pull back data from a SQL database. I have two OperationsContracts that return Lists, one brings back the initial Parent List and the second brings back the child List for any drill needed, these do not pull at the same time, one is the initial and the second is the on demand child dataset.

- Parent fields

  - Org_ID
  - Metric_ID
  - Element
  - Performance
  - Mean
- Child fields

  - Org_ID
  - Parent_ID
  - Metric_ID
  - Element
  - Performance
  - Mean

•   I access a stored procedure in SQL server to pull the datasets back and then put them in Lists. I pass the Parent.Org_ID from the selected row in the grid to the child stored procedure in the WCF Service and get the child dataset.

•   The million dollar question is how do I set the bindings or the ItemsSource for the nested grids?

Thanks so very much

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example:
http://blogs.perpetuumsoft.com/silverlight/how-to-turn-silverlight-datagrid-to-treegrid-in-15-minutes/

I modified the code a bit when I used it but I know I got lazy loading to work fairly easily.